# What is the most effective way to publish as much of your PhD thesis as you can?

Tags: publishability

Is it to try to summarize many chapters in one article, or you would try to publish standalone articles for each chapter?
I'm in Philosophy in the UK.
I have read that one should not try to squeeze an entire thesis into an article. In my case I have already published the long introductory chapter, so what's left are a list of criteria, case studies, and a conclusion.

Comment: What field and country are you in? Have you asked your supervisor about this?

Comment: Philosophy. UK. I have, but many answers and experiences are always better.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the dissertation and the field. Publishers want to publish significant results, not chapters. If you have several independently important results you can publish a lot of papers. If you have a dissertation with many results building to a main result, then maybe yes or maybe no, depending on the importance of those intermediate results.

But it is up to the editors and reviewers to make a judgement about publishing.

In some cases, a journal will be willing to publish a long article that contains all of your important results in a single paper. This gets the essence out without trying to salami slice the dissertation.

Comment: It is amazing how I can expect to receive a great answer from Buffy 5 minutes after asking, at any time of the day!

Comment: Actually, I'm a bot bot bot....cyborg that never sleeps.

Comment: LOL! Appreciate it.